# Why sudden drop in accuracy but loss still decreasing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, floating-accuracy

I am using *tensorflow* and *keras* for a binary classification problem.

I have only 121 samples, but 20.000 features. I know its too less samples and too many features, but its a biological problem (gene-expression data), so i have to deal with it.

**My question:** Why is accuracy (train and test) going up to 100%, then down and then increasing again. BUT loss is decreasing all the time?

Accuracy plot:

[image: accuracy plot]

Validation plot:

[image: validation plot]

Since my dataset is only 118 samples big i have only 24 test data points. See `confusion matrix`:
[image: confusion matrix]

This is my **neural network architecture:**

with current settings:
{'ann__dropout_rate': 0.4, 'ann__learning_rate': 0.01, 'ann__n_neurons': 16, 'ann__num_hidden': 1, 'ann__regularization_rate': 0.6}

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_shape, activation="relu",
                input_dim=input_shape))  # First Layer
model.add(Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu",
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(regularization_rate)))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

Thank you!

Comment: 1000 epochs over only a few samples? You're overfitting that data like crazy

Comment: I know. It was just like of a testing because i was wondering why accuracy is dropping down again but loss still decreasing. 
(also implemented EarlyStopping)

Answer (score 0):

try to shuffle your training data if you are not doing so already. You might also try a larger batch size. I also recommend using the ReduceLROnPlateau callback in model.fit. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) Set it up to monitor validation loss and to reduce the learning rate by a factor <1 if the loss fails to reduce after patience epochs.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Can you explain why i see this kind of accuracy curve?

Comment: It does not look like over fitting based on the graphs. Over fitting is characterized by the state where the training loss continues to decrease while the validation loss starts to increase. This usually occurs  in the later epochs.

Comment: Also with only 121 samples it is not surprising to see significant swings in the training and test data. If for example you only have 10 validation images a difference of just 1 change in the detection will swing the accuracy by 10%.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your @Gerry P ideas  (Shuffle=true) and ReduceLROnPlateau (batch size is 64). My callbacks are now:

`reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=1e-6, verbose=1)`

`early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=20, mode='auto')`

My Accuracy [accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZz01.png) and Loss [loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtdo8.png)  looks now like this:

I would say its still overfitted.

Confusion-Matrix:
[Confusionmatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfJTI.png)